Including the vector header results in VS Code incorrectly marking the usage of stderr as an error
In my project, I am using some C library functions in C++, and receiving what I'm not sure is an actual error or a failure of the intellisense.
The code compiles and runs correctly, yet vscode gives me this error when I use stderr from <cstdio>:
argument of type "FILE *" (aka "_iobuf *") is incompatible with parameter of type "FILE *" (aka "__file *") C/C++(167)
as well as:
#define stderr (__acrt_iob_func(2))

Expands to:

(__acrt_iob_func(2))

Here is a narrowed down version of the code. #include <vector> isn't used in this narrowed down version, only the larger program, but the error goes away when I remove that include, so I believe it has something to do with that, but I don't know why.
#include <cstdio>   // std::vprintf stderr
#include <vector>
#include <cstdarg>  // va_list va_start va_end

void print_error(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list  args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    std::vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);

    va_end(args);
}

int main(void) {
    print_error("Hello %s, %s!", "there", "world");

    return 0;
}

Here's a screenshot of the exact error squiggle:

Compilation and compiler:
D:\Desktop\test>g++ --version
g++ (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders, r1) 14.2.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


D:\Desktop\test>g++ test.cpp

D:\Desktop\test>a.exe
Hello there, world!
D:\Desktop\test>

I'm using the latest version of vscode (running "Code: Check for Updates..." in the command palette tells me "there are currently no updated available."), and the C/C++ extension by Microsoft for intellisense. Using "C/C++: Restart IntelliSense for Active File" in the command palette doesn't fix the issue.
I am wondering if there is a good reason for vscode to report this error, or if this is an issue with the intellisense since it compiles and runs fine?
If it is an error with the intellisense, is there something I can do to make it ignore this particular error without disabling all error squiggles?

VSCode in all of it's glory (and it is quite good), sometimes simply gets confused -- a nice way to put it. I've seen similar include issues and syntax highlight problems that are solved by closing and then restarting VSCode. I have no way of knowing if that is your issue here, but it can't hurt to try. (it did have a windows beginning -- so a restart is generally the first thing to try :)

do you have a c_cpp_properties.json? if so, what's in it? is your current configuration using the compiler you showed?

@starball I have no c_cpp_properties.json. I only have the one cpp file (and of course the a.exe file generated by the compiler). In the larger project I had more, but I narrowed down everything, in a separate folder, to just the one file containing the code above, in my question.
Also the compiler configuration shown above is also the exact one I used, and the entire terminal contents I provided were a direct copy paste.
1/2

@starball interestingly enough however, although earlier today I definitely still had the issue, I just went back while writing these comments to my original project and the separate test folder I used to double check just in case that nothing was generated, and the error is gone all of a sudden! I have made no changes at all to the test folder, so I'm not sure what changed. I did change the location of my mingw folder (for other unrelated reasons) and then restarted my pc (to update the system environment variables) so maybe one of those two things fixed the issue, but I'm not sure. 2/2

hm. is your compiler installation recent? maybe the cpptools process(es) just needed a restart to pick up the change?

@starball it is actually, yeah. I recently switched from 12.1.0 or something to 14.2.0 (the version in the post), so that could be the case.

so you can't repro this issue anymore (and don't know why it happened)? In that case, might be appropriate to close this question (maybe as "needs details/clarity") or you can try to repro by downgrading, restarting VS Code, then upgrading again and checking before restarting VS Code.

@starball Closing sounds good, but I'm not able to do it myself since (from searching it up) it looks like I'd need 250 repuation.
